LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: t9: i32 = mul nsw t23, t20
Hi I'm getting the following error
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: t9: i32 = mul nsw t23, t20   t23: i32,ch = load<(dereferenceable load (s32) from %ir.2)> t0, FrameIndex:i32<1>, undef:i32
    t5: i32 = FrameIndex<1>
    t3: i32 = undef   t20: i32,ch = load<(dereferenceable load (s32) from %ir.3)> t0, FrameIndex:i32<2>, undef:i32
    t7: i32 = FrameIndex<2>
    t3: i32 = undef In function: main

I have given CUSTOM_MUL iside the TISD in the TIselLowering.h file
namespace TISD {
enum NodeType {
  // Start the numbering from where ISD NodeType finishes.
  FIRST_NUMBER = ISD::BUILTIN_OP_END,
  CUSTOM_MUL,
  // Return
  Ret,
};
}

In TISelLowering.cpp
const char *TTargetLowering::getTargetNodeName(unsigned Opcode) const {
  switch (Opcode) {
  case TISD::Ret: return "TISD::Ret";
  case TISD::CUSTOM_MUL: return "TISD::CUSTOM_MUL";
  default:            return NULL;
  }
}

In Tinstrinfo.td file, defined the following:
def CUSTOM_MUL : SDNode<"ZSPISD::CUSTOM_MUL", SDTNone, []>;
class MAU32_rr<string opcodestr>
    : ZSPInst<(outs Int32Reg : $rZ32),
              (ins Int32Reg : $rX32, Int32Reg : $rY32),
              opcodestr, "$rZ32, $rX32, $rY32", []>;
def MUL32rr : MAU32_rr<"mul32">;
class PatInt32Int32<SDPatternOperator OpNode, ZSPInst Inst>
    : Pat<(OpNode Int32Reg : $rX32, Int32Reg : $rY32),
          (Inst Int32Reg : $rX32, Int32Reg : $rY32)>;
def : PatInt32Int32<mul, MUL32rr>;

Inside TIsekDAGtoDAG.cpp
void TDAGToDAGISel::Select(SDNode *Node) {
  SDLoc dl(Node);
  unsigned Opcode = Node->getOpcode();
  EVT VT = Node->getValueType(0);
  switch(Opcode) {
          case TISD::CUSTOM_MUL:
    {
      SDValue Op1 = Node->getOperand(0);
      SDValue Op2 = Node->getOperand(1);
      SDNode *Result = CurDAG->getMachineNode(T::MUL32rr, SDLoc(Node), MVT::i32, Op1, Op2);
      ReplaceNode(Node, Result);
    }
  }
}

This is the code that I have written, What should I modify?
